# Android text and image adapter for gridview in fragment

Tags: android, gridview, fragment, adapter

I have problem with gridview in frgament.... 
Please, i need your help !!!!

Code In frgament:

```
public class GridAdapterFragment extends Fragment{
String[]title;
Integer[]ids;
Database database;
String[] Description;
String[] Title;
int[] Minute;
int[] Hour;
int[] Day;
int[] Month;
int[] Year;
int mId;
int[]Ids;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup fragment1ODC, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1_od, fragment1ODC, false);
    database = new Database(view.getContext());
    int mId = database.getLastIdOD();
    title =new String[mId];
    Ids = new int[mId];
    ids = new Integer[mId];
    Title = new String[mId];
    Description = new String[mId];
    Minute = new int[mId];
    Hour = new int[mId];
    Day = new int[mId];
    Month = new int[mId];
    Year = new int[mId];
    database.close();
    for(int i=1;i==mId;i++){
        database = new Database(view.getContext());
        OneDayTD notification = database.getOneDay(i);
        database.close();
        if(notification.getActive()==1) {
            title[i-1] = notification.getTitle();
            Ids[i-1] = notification.getId();
            int idp = Integer.valueOf("R.drawable." +Integer.valueOf(notification.getIcon()));
            ids[i-1] = idp;
            Title[i-1] = notification.getTitle();
            Description[i-1] = notification.getContent();
            Minute[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getMinuteInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            Hour[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getHourInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            Day[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getDayInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            Month[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getMonthInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
            Year[i-1]= Integer.valueOf(getYearInt(notification.getDateAndTime()));
        }
    }
    TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewActiveOd);
    if(0<mId){
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridOdAdapter(view.getContext(),1,ids,Description,Title,Minute,Hour,Day,Month,Year));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                getActivity().finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),CreateOneDayActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mId",Ids[position]);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    });
    }else{
        textView.setText("You Haven't got any tasks !");
    }
    // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().
    return view;
}



    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

public String getMinuteInt(String i){
    Integer iN = Integer.valueOf(i);
    int d = iN % 100;
    String dS = Integer.toString(d);
    return  dS;
}

public String getHourInt(String i){
    Integer iN = Integer.valueOf(i);
    int d = iN % 10000;
    d = d/100;
    String dS = Integer.toString(d);
    return  dS;
}

public String getDayInt(String i){
    Integer iN = Integer.valueOf(i);
    int d = iN % 1000000;
    d = d/10000;
    String dS = Integer.toString(d);
    return  dS;
}
public String getMonthInt(String i){
    Integer iN = Integer.valueOf(i);
    int d = iN % 100000000;
    d = d/1000000;
    String dS = Integer.toString(d);
    return  dS;
}

public String getYearInt(String i){
    Integer iN = Integer.valueOf(i);
    int d = iN % 100000000;
    String dS = Integer.toString(d);
    return  dS;
}
}
```

Code  in adapter:

```
public class GridOdAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {
 String[] Description;
 String[] Title;
int[] Minute;
 int[] Hour;
int[] Day;
int[] Month;
int[] Year;
public Integer[] mThumbIds;

private Context mContext;
 int ACTIVE;

public GridOdAdapter(Context c,int active,Integer[] ids,String[] description, String[] title,int[] minute,int[] hour, int[] day,int[] month,int[] year) {
    mContext = c;
    ACTIVE = active;
    mThumbIds = ids;
    Description = description;
    Title = title;
    Minute = minute;
    Hour = hour;
    Day = day;
    Month = month;
    Year = year;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position-1];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        //LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_od,null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imagepart);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textpart);

        TextView textView2 = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.texttime);

        TextView textView4 = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.Timer);
        TextView textView5 = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.textpart2);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position-1]);
        textView.setText(Title[position-1]);
        textView5.setText(Description[position-1]);
        textView2.setText("Year: "+Year[position-1] + " Month: " + Month[position-1] + " Day: " + Day[position-1] + " Hour: "+ Hour[position-1] + " Minute: " + Minute[position-1]);
        textView4.setText(Title[position]);

    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }




    return grid;
}

// references to our images

}
```

And also Log:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.universe.time.officereminder, PID: 18976
                                                                                  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=-1
                                                                                      at com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.adapters.GridOdAdapter.getView(GridOdAdapter.java:81)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2828)
                                                                                      at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1064)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1139)
                                                                                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:729)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1071)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
                                                                                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
                                                                                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3012)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2298)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1345)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1588)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1230)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6748)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it obvious by the log statements? At line 45 of your GridOdAdapter it tries to get the length property of a null object. You're not passing any data to the adapter. Therefore the table is null. You should change your adapter constructor to something like this.

```
public GridOdAdapter(Context c, int active,Integer[] ids){
    context=c;
    ACTIVE=active;
    mThumbIds = ids;
}
```

Comment: hey guy , big thanks for help , but now i have another problem , please help me again , i has changed code of fragment and adapter and also changed Log

Comment: When an answer solves your problem you should mark it as accepted. As far as your other problem it's pretty obvious again. It says ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Your error is that you request the [position - 1]. Which when the position is 0 equals with -1. There is no index -1.==> error. Apart from that....stack overflow is not for other people to write your code for you. The errors that you requested our help for are extremely basic. Try your best to figure out by your self what is wrong with your code  before posting here. Otherwise you 'll never get better.